# Вёрстка и php

Tags: php

Вопрос глупый, но всё же: видел в вёрстке вставку функций (или не их) через фигурные скобки ( `{чего-то там}` ). Хотелось бы узнать, что это и зачем? Давно интересовался, но найти не смог, сам пользуюсь `<?php func();  ?>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Написал шаблонизатор, чем-то похож на юкозовский, работает отлично, есть вложенные условия

```
<if{condition}>$CODE$<else>$CODE_1$</if>
```

Все шаблоны хранятся в файла tpl, соответственно в них нет никакого php-кода.
Если заинтересовало - могу выслать.

---

Тест шаблонизатора — [**http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/**](http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/)

Исходники — [**http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/sfcdn.static.6s54h48tG4s.rar**](http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/sfcdn.static.6s54h48tG4s.rar)

Comment: Был бы очень признателен

Comment: Тест шаблонизатора — http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/
Исходники — http://f.static.sfcdn.soundsforge.net/sfcdn.static.6s54h48tG4s.rar

Надеюсь разберетесь.

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего это были шаблоны и как вариант Smarty в эту сторону и копай

Comment: всмысле шаблоны? т.е. если у меня движок самописный, то оно мне не надо?))

Comment: ну если хочешь использовать шаблонизатор - то да, ну и если у тебя более менее проект не маленький в виде нескольких страниц.

почитай в нете про шаблонизаторы.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило при использовании шаблонов так.

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда получал шаблон file_get_contents'ом, потом заменял str_replace'ом и выводил шаблон.