# Возможность выдачи сервером исходного кода

Tags: php

Вот в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90154/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0) вопросе меня заинтересовал приведенный в одном из ответов код.

```
/* безопасное соединение с базой данных, файл лежит перед корнем сайта если вдруг упадет php, логин и пароль к базе данных никто не сможешь увидеть */
include_once('../db-site.php');
```

Как я понимаю, автор боится того, что сервер Apache+PHP вместо выполнения PHP-сценария выдаст исходный код чистым текстом. Но ведь это должно быть невозможно в принципе (как я понимаю), ведь даже если PHP упал, то Apache при запросе в адресе *.php попытается запустить php, который лежит, а значит пользователь получит в ответ ошибку, или ничего.
**Вопрос**: при каких условиях возможна выдача сервером исходного кода?

Comment: Не знаю, но я сам лично такое видел.

Comment: @ReinRaus - это проблема не решается парой строчек в конфиге. Писать статью - нет желания

Comment: @ReinRaus, вопрос не в тему, но Вы, вроде, с регулярками дружны: можно ли одним выражением взять только определённую группу символов, которые перемешаны с лишними? Т. е. из строки: "id: 12_42; key: 123" взять "1242"?

Comment: Можно. Для этого надо будет применять замену по регулярному выражению, а не поиск. Замене подлежит весь текст, кроме нужного.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Если сервер неправильно сконфигурирован, то он может показать исходный РНР код.

Comment: Дааа... Как-то это даже в голову не приходило... А ведь так и есть... Просто include как я понял нужно делать на лежащий вне папки DOCUMENT_ROOT файл PHP, так?

Comment: @Dobby007, да.

Установите Джумлу, отключите PHP и через минуту я с вашей базой буду делать что захочу.

Comment: Помню еще у фейсбука была такая байда. На хабре можно найти код пары страниц, а то и больше

Comment: Ну теперь значит буду переносить свой Index))))) Можно кстати... Попробовать сделать htaccess и поставить проверку в нем на <IfModule>. Не знаю как будет работать и будет ли работать вообще, но попробовать можно....

Comment: @Dobby007, вряд ли сработает, апач проверяет просто загруженность модуля, насколько мне это видится, а работает PHP или нет это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Dex, я с вами согласен... Может быть и такое... Это на практике надо проверять. Php убивать, и смотреть, что изменится. Это так... полет мыслей был))

Comment: @Dobby007, только что проверил. Тесты: 1) убираем только AddHandler из конфига апача (у меня эти директивы идут отдельным файлом, включаемым в httpd.conf - тупо переименовал файл); 2) комментируем директиву LoadModule, подгружающую разделяемую библиотеку с PHP; 3) удаляем сам файл разделяемой библиотеки mod_php5.so;

Во всех трех случаях апач отдал исходник. Тестовая машина, если что:
`Linux dante.heathen.prv 3.1.9-1.4-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 27 08:55:10 UTC 2012 (efb5ff4) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @northerner, да я особо на этот метод не надеялся. Просто сказал как вариант. А вы удаляли mod_php5.so при запущенном apache? А вообще я сделал вот как. Оставил в index.php только один инклуд, а весь код поместил в файл, находящейся в ПОДПАПКЕ (т.е. без никаких "../"). И заблокировал через mod_rewrite в httpd.conf к этой подпапке доступ (ну и ко всему остальному, что я не хотел оставлять открытым). По всем показателям все должно быть защищенным. И если PHP и откажет, то пользователь увидит только один include и больше ничего.

Comment: Если злоумышленник добьется того, что у вас ляжет интерпритатор - include вас уже не спасет

Comment: @AlexWindHope, PHP не только от этого может леч.

Comment: @Dobby007, нет, апач каждый раз перезапускал. Библиотека подгружается при старте апача, если в процессе удалить .so не влияет.

Comment: @exec - спасибо кэп. Если PHP ляжет по вашей вине то это **как-бы** "немного" другая тема разговора, не?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, тут приводили примеры как ложился php на FaceBook, не суть, почему он ложился. Возможно, что на один запрос сервер выдал исходники, а на другой точно такой же запрос через микромикросекунду он выдал нормальную страницу. Главное, что это происходило, не важно по какой причине, и нет оснований обвинять людей, что они врут, что фейсбук выдал листинг.

Comment: @ReinRaus - листинг может отдаваться при очень больших нагрузках и то, исключительно теоритически. То, что хранить пароль и логин БД отдельно хорошо и удобно и так и надо делать - знает любой junior.

В 99.9999% случаев о таких проблемах даже не стоит задумываться т.к. не актуально.

Без обоснований загружаться подобными проблемами - всего-лишь параноя. И вместо того, чтобы выдумывать как не показать важные куски кода нужно сделать так, чтобы код не выводился не при каких обстояельствах.

Comment: И на фейсбуке он выводился лишь потому, что люди просто не предусмотрели этого (или, скажем так - не до конца =))

Comment: @AlexWindHope, приведите, пожалуйста пример, как не выдать index.php ни при каких обстояельствах.

Answer (score 10):

к чему столько паники, пишем адекватный .htaccess перенаправляющий все запросы на index.php , в index.php только инклюды необходимых файлов (ядра, контроллера и т.д.) и всё даже если пхп упадет пользователь получит листинг только файла index.php а извращаться и хранить файл подключения к бд под корнем сайта это, извините, параноя.

Comment: Получив листинг индекса, мы получим имена файлов ядра,контроллера. 
Открываем их, получаем еще код + адреса класов работы с мускулем а то и сразу конфига. И так перебираясь от файла к файлу можно весь сайт скопировать))))

Comment: @lnart, так-то да.

Comment: @lnart и @exec... А я че-то сказал и щас только подумал... Как он получит весь сайт если htaccess заблокирует все запросы к файлам системы кроме индекса???

Comment: @lnart @exec прежде чем подобное утверждать, я бы поррекомендовал проверить на практике.

Comment: Что проверять то? Вы думаете что все сайты надо писать, чтоб запросы шли через индекс? ЧПУ в топку да? ок. 
п.с Немного не так что ЧПУ выразился, но суть понятна.
А чтоб решить эту проблему, надо то всего вынести конфиг на уровень выше доступного и все. а в .htaccess прописать чтоб инклудил

Comment: @FLK, я не сказал что мое решение — единственное решение данной проблемы.

Comment: А как по-другому реализовать ЧПУ если не через index???

Comment: @lnart вы по всей видимости, не знакомы с реализацией ЧПУ на стороне сервера. либо невнимательно прочли мой ответ. P.S. @lnhart не надо переносить ни какой уровень не выше не ниже,если этого не требует файловая структура проекта. как верно, было замечено выше .htaccess перенавправит ВСЕ запросы на index.php

Comment: Что вы спорите непонятно о чем, файлы ядра, БД и прочего скрытого, именуйте по-особенному, добавляйте дополнительное расширение, а в .htaccess разрешите чтение только расширения `*.php`. @FLK, толково сказал, не конкретизируя, что нужно сделать, а как это сделать, полет фантазии подскажет.

Comment: @Dex чревато тем что придется прописывать разрешения для исполнениея js, css, png, jpg и других файлов которые необходимо будет вывести на сайте. хотя последнее время всё больше склоняюсь к подобному решению.доступ к файлам только через контроллер.

Comment: Ничего не нужно прописывать, закинули файл до корня, прописали index. Всё, какие проблемы? Минутное дело и база защищена.

Comment: > файлы db.inc.php мы отправляем на index.php

Не понял этого.

Comment: @exec, вы через htaccess запрещаете доступ к файлам в которых, есть какая-то подстрока, или специальное расширение, перенаправляя запросы к index.php, например. С вами тоже согласен, что перекинуть файл в другую директорию проще, но не всегда может быть такая возможность, к сожалению, у себя я такого не предусмотрел. Поэтому всегда есть место изврату.

Comment: @exec как то оно не по феншую ) да и не всегда бывает возможность доступа "до корня"

Comment: @FLK, но оно работает быстрее нежели с .htaccess, хотя этому сейчас уделяют мало внимания.

Comment: @Dex листинг htaccess можно включить в конфигурацию apache, и он будет читаться один раз при загрузки сервера

Comment: @Dobby007, тогда вы теряете его возможности на время работы сервера, что тоже не всегда хорошо.

Answer (score 8):

Не извращайтесь так) В index.php пишем инклуд, весь остальной код ограничиваем какой-то папкой. У меня получилось такое:

```
#.htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^system/.*/$ /404.html [L] #папки
RewriteRule ^system/.*\.php$ /404.html [L] #.php
```

Ну а если ляжет поддержка .htaccess - скорее всего это будет означать, что лег апач.

Comment: +1. Я ту же самую мысль изложил выше. Можно вообще в httpd.conf код блокировки htaccess'а вставить. И если mod_rewrite слетел, апач просто ошибку выдаст при загрузки. И ни один файл вообще не загрузится ни в каком виде... Ну это так... К слову. mod_rewtite чтоб слетел, это еще постараться нужно...

Answer (score 3):

У меня сделано как. Я сторонник меньшего числа вхождений в программу. Т.е:
Есть index.html и api.php - они лежат в /var/www/web/ <--- Web Root path, и есть куча файлов за ней. (/var/www/core/*.php).

В Api.php есть строка, которая подключает стартап файл с модулями (при require, в отличии от простого "include" разница во времени незаметна).
Например.

```
api.php  -- require -> ../core/start.php
start.php -- require -> ./*.php
```

Api.php содержит Класс, который в зависимости от запроса будет задействовать тот или иной класс и отдавать нужную информацию.

Тем самым я себя защитил от:

1. Если ляжет php, никто все равно не получит исходники. Все равно в api.php нет ничего такого, что помогло бы злоумышленнику ломануть ту..или иную штуку.
2. Чем меньше число вхождений в программу, тем проще контролировать корректность запросов => Если будет замечена дыра - ее будет оч. просто ее прикрыть :)

Собственно, все :)

Comment: Как-то не особо понял.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы исходники не стащили, достаточно закодировать скрипты хоть тем же Zend Guard. 
Ну а если у Вас свой сервер, пусть и виртуальный, но с отключенной возможностью удаленного подключения к БД, то "украденные" пароли ничем не помогут.

Ну а если у Вас нет денег ни на приличный хостинг, ни на Zend Guard, то кому нужно Вас "ломать"?

Answer (score 2):

Падение пыха не обязательно. Достаточно в htaccess, а лучше в php.ini прописать такое:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
```

И сервер будет выдавать вместо результатов вычислений красивый подсвеченный исходник.

Comment: Ну это-то понятно. Интересен вариант, когда все настроено на запуск сценария, а отдается исходный код.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше писать код так, чтобы его можно было выложить хоть на GitHub и ничего секретного не ушло.

А доступы к базе данных, ключи к API хранить в переменных окружения (http://12factor.net/ru/config) или вообще в стороннем сервисе (https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/consul/)