# Глобальные переменные

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Как можно задать для PHP глобальные переменные, причем указать их надо вне скрипта PHP, то есть в php.ini или иным образом.
Для упрощения мысли поясню зачем это нужно:
Мы предполагаем, что PHP может выдать листинг нашей программы [пруфлинк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90539/php-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
Мы не хотим делать подключение выше корня root, потому что размещение соединения с базой данных в отдельном файле есть лишнее чтение одного файла при запуске любого файла php на сервере, хотя подключение к БД требует всего одной строчки кода 
В идеале хотелось бы нечто вроде:

```
$db=mysql_connect("localhost", $_SERVER['sql_user'], $_SERVER['sql_user_pass']);
```

То есть при запуске любого скрипта php в нем сразу определены некие глобальные переменные.
**РЕШЕНИЕ**
httpd.conf

```
SetEnv sql_user root
SetEnv sql_user_pass root
```

index.php

```
mysql_connect('localhost', getenv('sql_user'), getenv('sql_user_pass'));
```

Comment: parse_ini_file, зачем нужна опциональная глобальная перменная, если можно создать свою, написав свой cool класс и запускать ее глобально в нужных местах?!

Может меня кто-то поправит, но подхода со стороны опциональных глобов я не видел!

Comment: Чем вам не нравится вариант который в теме по вашей ссылке?

Comment: @exec 
    
    размещение соединения с базой данных в отдельном файле есть лишнее чтение одного файла при запуске любого файла php
Да, это не существенно, но Вам интересно было бы найти решение, которое более эффективно? Мне например интересно. Поиск ничего похожего не дал. Значит надо обращаться к сакральным знаниям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для извращенцев:

```
#.htaccess
SetEnv mysqlUser root
SetEnv mysqlPassword 12345

//connect.php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', $_ENV['mysqlUser'], $_ENV['mysqlPassword']) or die();
```

Скрытие дот-файлов настроено почти везде. Почти - это с учетом теории вероятности, я выклеченного не видел.

Comment: вот жешь на минуту опоздал ) с таким же ответом

Comment: @Sh4dow для совсем параноиков, можно добавить такое вот правило )
RewriteRule^.htaccess$-[F]

Comment: Это неплохо. Если записать это в httpd.conf, то получится создание этих переменных при старте сервера.  
Только к сожалению не получается. Ubuntu. Добавил в apache.conf, httpd.conf, .htaccess строку  
    
    SetEnv test test
print_r($_ENV); дает пустой массив.  
mod_env для Apache кажется включен.
P.S. Ведь если конфиг мода в apache2/mods-enabled, то мод включен ?

Comment: Я тут если честно ничего не скажу, но в своих работах эту штуку использовал и на адекватных хостингах не было проблем. Проверьте для начала чтобы оба файла ( .php и .htaccess ) в одной папке были, дальше подбором)

Comment: @Sh4dow, на адекватном хостинге тоже не работает.

Comment: Заработало вот так
**.htaccess**
    
    SetEnv test test
**test.php**  
    
    echo getenv('test');
Массив $_ENV пустой при этом.