# Практическая польза буферизации

Tags: php, производительность

Рассмотрим три подхода к организации вывода данных
**1:**

```
ob_start();
$arr=Array('email', 'name', 'psw');
echo '<FORM method=post action="/">\n';
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) echo '<INPUT name="'.$v.'" /><BR/>\n';
echo '<INPUT type=submit value=GO /></FORM>';
ob_end_flush();
```

**2:**

```
$arr=Array('email', 'name', 'psw');
echo '<FORM method=post action="/">\n';
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) echo '<INPUT name="'.$v.'" /><BR/>\n';
echo '<INPUT type=submit value=GO /></FORM>';
```

**3:**

```
$arr=Array('email', 'name', 'psw');
$buffer='<FORM method=post action="/">\n';
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) $buffer.='<INPUT name="'.$v.'" /><BR/>\n';
$buffer.='<INPUT type=submit value=GO /></FORM>';
echo $buffer;
```

Какие могут быть преимущества/недостатки трех подходов ?

Comment: @Expert, исправил бы уже массивы.

Comment: Ну, в любом случае - 3-й вариант будет быстрее остальных. 
Дело в том, что проще сначала собрать кучу и один раз ее выплюнуть, чем выплевывать ее по частям  :)

Хотя, если честно, никогда не юзал "ob_". Судя по коду, она делает примерно то же, что и вариант 3 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак, почти не соврал))

Результат (100000 итераций)

```
0.01069092750549 // echo 'a';
0.03983998298645 // ob_start(); ... ob_end_flush(); // я, кстати, удивлен
0.00910401344299 // $buffer .= 'a'; 
0.11031794548035 // ?>a<? // а здесь нет
```

Аааа соврал, я с включенной штатной буферизацией делал (`ob_implicit_flush(0)` которая)

Вот теперь результаты, нате:

```
0.83298802375793
0.00991582870483
0.00921082496643
0.36798715591431
```

[Пруф](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test41.php) прилагается.

Еще прошу учесть, что запись вида

```
<? if ($condition) { ?>
a<?=$a?>a
<? } else { ?>
b<?=b?>b
<? } ?>
```

это 6 echo, а не 2.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: +100 за тест)

Comment: [http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test39.php#][1] :D ниче так ваще.


[1]: http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test39.php#

Comment: O_o @exec, с чего такая щедрость?) В любом случае благодарю)

@FLK, последний апдейт как раз для вас)) Каждое ?><? - переключение режима интерпретатора, что не есть хорошо. Тем более когда их несколько, можно даже без таких утрированных тестов уйти в таймаут.

Comment: @Sh4dow, а что с тестами с 1 по 25? http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test( 1 - 25 ).php

Comment: @exec еще раз @Sh4dow ) Отличный тест из которого сразу видно, что при множественном echo эффективнее всего использовать буферизацию.  
Немного отстает по скорости собственный буфер в виде $buffer. Остальные способы менее эффективны.

Comment: @ReinRaus, что еще раз?

Comment: @exec уже просто нет комментария **Кому еще +100** я про это

Comment: @Sh4dow либо я что то делаю не так, либо не могу понять, не могли бы вы потестить варианты как есть? в полном объеме?

Comment: @FLK, итерации убавил до 30к,

    1.7586960792542
    2.4372880458832
    6.5043621063232

Но в случае с буфером учитывайте, что там уже другое выходит на первый план - конкатенация немалой части памяти с несколькими символами, для чего эту строку надо скопировать. Ибо на сотне итераций результат такой:

    0.00033402442932 // буфер ob_      1х
    0.04811692237854 // echo         160х
    0.00047397613525 // $buffer      1.4х
    0.00211811065673 // ваш вариант    7x

Ссылку не дам, меня хостер забанит нафиг за такие тесты))

Comment: это уже похоже на мои результаты. в итоге приходим к тому, что в разных ситуациях выгодней разные варианты.

Comment: @FLK, Вы можете привести результаты Ваших тестов? Как я понял они расходятся с данными @Sh4dow

Comment: Я лично пришел к тому, что надо пользоваться встроенной буферизацией (ибо она изначально под большие объемы оптимизирована) и не парить мозг. И запомнить, что самая тяжелая операция(в контексте php и работы с текстом) - вывод, ибо там свое берут сеть, сокеты, пинги и пр., а браузеры оптимизированы под прием больших блоков.

В общем, юзаем `ob_*`, радуемся, улыбаемся и машем. А конструкцию `<?=$a?>` оставляем на кэшируемые шаблоны, для верстальщиков, ибо здесь выгода от нее есть только в этом случае. А серию echo - на сокетные приложения, где важна моментальная передача.

Вот такие пироги =)

Comment: @ReinRaus в одном из комментариев к своему ответу приводил. 10к прогонов. и если привести к общему знаменателю, то результат будет тот же что и у @Sh4dow.

Comment: > И запомнить, что самая тяжелая операция(в контексте php и работы с текстом) - вывод, ибо там свое берут сеть, сокеты, пинги и пр., а браузеры оптимизированы под прием больших блоков.

Это верно, но не забывайте, что implict flush по умолчанию выключен (кстати, строка `ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');` в вашем тесте [бессмысленная](http://php.net/outcontrol.configuration)), по этому, если явная буферизация не требуется, то обычный echo будет предпочтительнее.

Кроме того, многое зависит от веб сервера и удаленности клиента.

Comment: Результаты вашего-же теста у меня, но с выключенным implict flush:

    0.024953842163086
    0.024777889251709
    0.026643991470337
    0.024849891662598

Answer (score 2):

> $arr={'email', 'name', 'psw'};

PHP 5.9?

---

Делайте так, как Вам нужно.

[В моей CMS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90154#90410), например, есть только **один** `echo`.

Comment: @exec js-edition

Comment: Это короткая запись массива, начиная с недавно вышедшей версией 5.4

Comment: @johniek_comp, нет, это вообще что-то не понятное, и даже не `JS`. 

В PHP 5.4 такого нет. Там как в `JS` — `[]`.

Comment: точно, не обратил внимания.

Comment: а где можно посмотреть твою cms? если она не сверхсекретна)

Comment: Добавил ссылку в ответ.

Comment: нормальненько так, но про MVC ничего не сказано, вдруг у вас там все вместе клеится :)

Comment: @johniek_comp, в каком смысле вместе клеится?

Answer (score 0):

Все три медленные, а первый так вообще непонятно к чему. лучше сделать так:

```
$arr=array('email', 'name', 'psw');
?><FORM method=post action="/"><?
foreach ($arr as $v) 
{?><INPUT nsme="<?=$v?>" /><BR/><?}?>
<INPUT type=submit value=GO /></FORM>
```

и быстрей и наглядней.

**Добавлено:**
по вашим примерам самый медленный третий вариант, конкатенация строк только для вывода это нехорошо. затем первый вариант и с мизерным отрывом по скорости второй.

Comment: FALSE, переключение режиме интрепретация/вывод намного дороже эхо, а эхо несколько раз дороже `ob_*`. Ща будет тест.

Comment: @Sh4dow на 10к проходов мой вариант - 0.027, первый-второй вариант почти одинаково ~0.033, третий вариант 0.04

Comment: буферизацию отключите полностью и повторите :) у меня в тесте есть код)

Comment: в том то и дело что отключил.

Comment: <? if ($condition) { ?>
    a<?=$a?>a
    <? } else { ?>
    b<?=b?>b
    <? } ?>

отрывать я бы не стал, но по оным линейкой надавал бы за такое :)

во первых, short code не везде включен, его даже рекомендуют выключать, во вторых:
писать нужно хотя бы так:

<?php if ($condition): ?>
somecode
<?php else: ?>
somecode else
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @shurik писать можно и так и так на скорость это сильно не повлияет (хотя мои замеры утверждают что вообще не влияет), а вот мой любимый редактор пока не воспринимает if и endif как пару и не хочет их подсвечивать :( и вот это уже критично особенно при отладке.
пока еще ни разу не сталкивался с хостингами у которых отключен short code.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант более меньше, и по этому как бы лучше, но это смотря какая задача перед вами стоит. В разных ситуациях по-разному, каждый имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: более меньше это как?

Comment: по кол-во строк, символов имел в виду