# Что лучше: много echo или большая переменная

Tags: php

Пример. Данные выбираются из БД в цикле. Какой вариант лучше?

**I.**

```
for()
{
    echo $var;
}
```

**II.**

```
$result="";  
for()  
{  
    $result=$result.$var;  
}  
echo $result;
```

$var - переменная в которой информация из строки/ячейки БД, $result - переменная, в которой будет храниться вся выводимая информация.

Какой из вариантов лучше по скорости/нагрузке/и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для читаемости, скорости выполнения и меньшего использования памяти лучше первый вариант. 
второй же вариант пригоден для функции которая должна возвращать выводимый текст в переменную.
**пример:**

```
function get_text($rows,$print=true){
$out='';
foreach($rows as $row){
$out.=$row;
}
if($print)echo $out;
return $out;
}
```

данная функция вернет текст в переменной если $print=false, и распечатает по умолчанию либо если $print=true

Answer (score 4):

Вообще особой разницы нет. Здесь уже как вам удобнее, так и поступайте. Если вы ищите способы оптимизации приложения, то не там ищете. Надо копать в сторону кеширования страниц,  правильного выбора веб-сервера и т.д

Comment: *кеширования

Comment: абсолютно поддерживаю ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Этот подход называется буферизацией вывода. Для буферизации в PHP предусмотрены штатные средства.

Функция [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php) включает режим буферизации. После этого весь вывод `echo` и обычных HTML-вставок перенаправляется в буфер.

[`ob_end_flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-end-flush.php) сбрасывает буфер и выводит его. Если вы хотите использовать содержимое буфера, то вам необходимо вызвать [`ob_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php) перед `ob_end_flush()`.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91125/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) уже обсуждалась практическая польза буферизации в PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Как тебе будет удобнее работать, поскольку особой разницы между вариантами нет

Comment: а если в цикле будут тысячи или сотни тысяч итераций, то в как будет вести себя второй вариант? а конкретно переменная $result