# explode URl

Tags: ооп, php

Есть такой URL

**site.com/class/method**

кто работал с фрейворками сразу поймет...

задача, подключить класс *class*, и запустить метод *method*, если метод не указан - грузить *index* метод.

делаю так:

```
$route = empty($_GET['route']) ? '' : $_GET['route'];

$exp = explode('/', $route);
$controller = new $exp[0];
 if(method_exists($controller, $exp[1])) {
    call_user_func(array($controller, $exp[1]));
    } else {
    $controller->index ();    
    }
```

класс находит, подключает, а метод никак, а пишет:
**Notice: Undefined offset: 1 в $exp[1]...**

посоветуйте как быть

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!empty($exp[1]) and method_exists($controller, $exp[1])) {
```

Не за что)

И вообще совет: подключаете autoload, потом что-то такое:

```
$route = !empty($_GET['route']) ? $_GET['route'] : '';
$exp = explode('/', $route);
$class = (empty($exp[0]) or !class_exists($exp[0])) ? 'IndexClass' : $exp[0];
$controller = new $class;
$method = (empty($exp[1]) or !method_exists($controller, $exp[1])) ? 'index' : $exp[1];
$controller->$method();
```

Comment: не работает, я так пробовал уже :) 

если я делаю 

$exp = explode('/', $route);
print_r($exp);

то возвращает Array ( [0] => class ) т.е. второй элемент не существует, про что мне говорит нотис...а если делаю вар_дамп, то находит 2 элемента class и method...

Comment: Обновил, пробуйте.

Comment: Все равно Notice: Undefined offset: 1, ошибок в логике нет, тут проблема в том что не находит method в url

Comment: Не доглядел пару моментов, вообщем заработало, всем спасибо. Кто помогал +1.

Comment: Я вам еще посоветую префикс какой-то организовать. А то кто-нибудь додумается так с вас инфу слить. Что-то вроде `'myCMS_'.$exp[0]` будет.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, если я пишу такие системы(ядра), можно ли мне идти на работу PHP программистом, хватит ли силенок?

Comment: @johniek_comp - рассылайте резюме, ездите на вью, рано или поздно работу найдете (скорее рано т.к. востребованность на высоком уровне).

Ну и смотрите по требованиям к вакансиям - если есть что-то, что часто встречается, но вы этого не знаете - изучите

Comment: Согласен )

Answer (score 1):

Если я ошибаюсь, то скажите, в чем именно.
Если я правильно понял, то речь идет об автозагрузке классов?

```
function __autoload($class)   // глобальный метод, определенный в интерпретаторе PHP
{
include_once($class.".php");
}

$cat = new cat();  //__autoload
$dog = new dog();  //__autoload
```

Comment: Да. Именно, но как это роль играет?

Comment: если бы вы внимательно посмотрели вопрос то вы увидели бы

    $controller = new $exp[0];
то есть классы уже подгружаются, и создаются объекты, у него методы не подключает

Comment: Ну, к примеру, если у вас каждый класс вынесен в отдельный файл, то автозагрузка будет подключать классы динамически, по мере их добавления.

Comment: Ненавижу __autoload, ИМХО - никому не нужная магия

Comment: @AlexWindHope, очень полезная это вещь, когда классов много и раскиданы они все по разным файлам...но в крайнем случае можно написать функционал этой функции по-своему...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
/*
*   FrontController
*   @singletone
*/
class FrontController {
    //  typical singletone initialization
    private static $_instance = null;
    private function __construct(){}
    private function __clone(){}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_instance == null) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    //---------------------------------
    //  FrontCotroller initialization
    //---------------------------------
    public function init() {
        $frontUrlData = $this->prepareUrl();
        $frontUrlDataLength = count($frontUrlData);

        if(!$frontUrlData) {    //  if url data empty - then it's Home controller
            loadController('Home');
            $controller = new Home();
            $controller->index();
        }
        else if($frontUrlDataLength === 1) {
            $controllerName = ucfirst($frontUrlData[0]);
            if(controllerExists($controllerName)) {
                loadController($controllerName);
                $controllerInstance = new $controllerName();
                $controllerInstance->index();
            }
            else {
                // 404
            }
        }
        else if($frontUrlDataLength > 1) {
            $controllerName = ucfirst($frontUrlData[0]);
            if(controllerExists($controllerName)) {
                loadController($controllerName);
                $controllerInstance = new $controllerName();
                $methodName = $frontUrlData[1];
                if(method_exists($controllerInstance, $methodName)) {
                    $controllerInstance->$methodName();
                    exit();
                }
            }
            // 404
        }
    }

    private function prepareUrl() {
        //  first we need to clean GET data
        $urlData = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $url = $urlData['path']; // we clear all GET data from url
        //  no we need to explode url data
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        //  no we need to clear empty copy of exploded url array
        $url = array_merge(array_diff($url, array('')));
        //  no our cleared url data ready to return
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Подразумевается, что все контроллеры наследуют абстрактный класс, в котором определен абстрактный метод index. Home - контроллер по умолчанию, все имена классов должны совпадать с именем файлов и начинаться с большой буквы. Там где указано `// 404` - вызывайте свой notFound метод.

Так-же необходимо реализовать функции `controllerExists` и `loadController`.Можно обойтись и без этого и писать в лоб, типа `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/' . $className`, но я не сторонник такого подхода. К тому-же, так будет проще использовать класс.  Делается это примерно так:

```
function controllerExists($controllerName) {
    if(file_exists(controllerRoot($controllerName))) {
        return true;
    }
}

function loadController($controllerName) {
    include_once controllerRoot($controllerName);
}

// где controllerRoot функция вида
function controllerRoot($controllerName = false) {
    $baseRoot = ''; // здесь путь к корневой папке контроллеров
    if($controllerName) {
        $baseRoot .= $controllerName . '.php';
    }
    return $baseRoot;
}
```

Собственно юзать так:

```
 FrontController::getInstance() -> init();
```

Естественно если вам не нужен непосредственно такой функционал, либо у вас не получилось что-то конкретное, либо вас что-то не устраивает в коде вы можете сделать по своему или, в случае если что-то не получилось - "содрать" необходимый блок кода.

Comment: Для чего метод `getInstance`?

Comment: [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Вообще я очень давно это писал, в целом, в данном конкретном примере, он не нужен. Но этот класс был сильно переписан в процессе и на его основе было выстроено еще немало функционала, вот там-то и пригодилось то, что это singletone. Да и раз так сделано в Zend'e, значит так правильно (что, что а с ООП в нем все в порядке)

Comment: Я не пойму, для чего делать так: 

    Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();

Если можно сделать так:

    Class::action();

?

Comment: Если хотите узнать что такое одиночка и зачем этот шаблон нужен - задавайте вопрос, мой ответ определенно не вместиться в комментарий. 

Или почитайте книгу о шаблонах проектирования, если и потом не поймете - значит еще не доросли

Если очень кратко - нужно понимать разницу между вызовом статического метода и вызовом экземпляра класса. В случае вызова `Class::action()` этого самого экземпляра у нас попросту нет.

Comment: Ок, завтра задам.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90154#90410) четко и понятно расписано как сделать такое.

Сделайте всё как там сказано, только содержимое файла `controller_messages.php` замените на вот это:

```
class controller_messages {
    function delegate($alias) {
        if ( method_exists(get_class(), $alias[1]) ) {
            return self::$alias[1](); 
        } else {
            exit('Error');
        }
    }

    function messages() {
        switch(engine::$alias[1]) {
            case 'add' : 
                $ex = 'add message';
                break;
            case 'edit' : 
                $ex = 'edit message';
                break;
            default :
                $ex = 'all messages';
                break;
        }
        core::$content = $ex;
    }
}
```

Собственно всё что вам нужно:

- **site.ru/messages/** -> all messages
- **site.ru/messages/add/** -> add messages
- **site.ru/messages/edit/** -> edit messages