# Настройка .htaccess файла

Tags: .htaccess

**Друзья,** составила .htaccess файлик, но что-то сомнения у меня, боюсь сайт обвалится. Решения от вас не нужно, просто подскажите если двигаюсь не в том направление. Буду дорабатывать.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/

AddType image/x-icon .ico

<Files ".htaccess">
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.html$ index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php

RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ index.php?next=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?next=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3&zuma=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3&zuma=$4

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] .
```

Comment: меня конец смущает где редирект стоит на www

Comment: в принципе он тут и не нужен, разве что для сео, но тогда надо и другие похожие варианты редиректить, как например слеш в конце адреса. и index.php и далее в зависимости от структуры сайта. а так можно заменить на RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA] и смысл будет тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteEngine on дважды в коде встречается, это никчему.  да и зачем столько правил указывать, по мне так проще переадресовать всё на index.php а там уже разобрать.
что то типа:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
```

а так вы заставляете сервер выполнять кучу однотипных регулярок.

Comment: Да, сделайте так, как сказал @FLK. По [**этой**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90154#90410) ссылке можно посмотреть как это делается.