# Дубли страниц  /index.php?pages=

Tags: .htaccess, php, html

В данный момент файл `.htaccess` имеет вид:

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]+)?$ index.php?pages=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]+)?/([0-9a-z_-]+)?$ index.php?parameter=$1&pages=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Как избавится от урлов вида `/index.php?pages=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90154/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: ой там просто умница, мне нужно в htaccess это сделать, а в пхпыхе омжно 4 строки написать с регуляркой что бы он отдавал 404 и все вот пример за 5 минут:
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $substr="/index.php?pages=";
        if (strstr($url, $substr))
        {
            $page404='ok';
      header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); 
        }
Так это вродь нормалды мне интересно в htaccess можно убрать эти дубли страниц или нет?

Comment: Не понял, что за дубли?

Comment: суть в чем в данный момент у меня страница новостей доступна по следующим адресам ( робот проиндексировал ) /news а так же /index.php?pages=news вот и мне интересно как средствами htaccess избавится от этого

Comment: Это вам нужен robots.txt

Comment: в роботсе придется на каждую ссылку прописывать эт я знаю (

Comment: Ну можно сделать проверку в `index.php`.