# Работа со smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Из за подключения smarty у меня перестаёт работать функция **autoload. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим и знает как сделать так, чтобы** autoload работала нормально при smarty?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно smarty?

Comment: А что вы посоветуете другой шаблонизатор?

Comment: Совет в ответе.

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: [Вёрстка и php](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/69622)

Answer (score 1):

```
Вот кусок кода из smarty, который как я думаю влияет на __autoload
if (!defined('SMARTY_SPL_AUTOLOAD')) {
    define('SMARTY_SPL_AUTOLOAD', 0);
}

if (SMARTY_SPL_AUTOLOAD && set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . SMARTY_SYSPLUGINS_DIR) !== false) {
    $registeredAutoLoadFunctions = spl_autoload_functions();
    if (!isset($registeredAutoLoadFunctions['spl_autoload'])) {
        spl_autoload_register();
    } 
} else {
    spl_autoload_register('smartyAutoload');
}
```

Comment: Правильно думаете - [spl_autoload_register][1]

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: что-то я не совсем понял, что делает эта функция

Comment: Устанавливает функцию авто погрузчика. [**Автоматическая подгрузка файлов с PHP-классами**][1]

[1]: http://www.codeisart.ru/php-class-files-autoload/

Comment: я так понял через функцию spl_autoload_register можно задавать функцию, которая будет выступать в качестве __autoload. Т.е. я могу назвать функцию function zagruzka(), и если я пропишу spl_autoload_register('zagruzka'), то моя функция zagruzka() будет работать как __autoload

Comment: @Артур Лоденев, да, Вы правильно поняли.