# Шаблонизатор

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Решил переписать [**свой шаблонизатор**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69622#69669), ввести **глобальные коды**, **elseif**.

**Какой шаблонизатор я вижу в будущем:**

```
$SOME_CODE$ — обычный код.

<if{$SOME_CODE$}>some code is true</if> — простое условие

<if{$SOME_CODE$}>
  <if{$ALIAS_1$ == 123 && $QUERY$ == 'search'}>
    true
  <else>
    <if{$TRUE$}>
      true
    <else>
      false
    </if>
  </if>
<elseif{$ALIAS_0$ == '/'}>
  index
</if> — сложное условие
```

Вопрос в том, что, по вашему мнению, необходимо добавить в функционал?

Шаблонизатор который указан в ссылке поста, давно используется на многих моих проектах, поэтому не нужно говорить, что я создаю велосипед. У меня есть более менее прямые руки, голова, и я хочу развиваться, получать новый опыт.

---

**UPD:** На чем лучше парсить условия и циклы? Регулярные выражения или строковые функции?

Comment: По поводу велосипеда, я тоже накатал свой Templater и ни разу не думал о том что это велосипед! Так что если мозг позволяет это делать, почему бы это не делать?! И пусть себе говорят :)

Comment: Настоящий ученый не будет спрашивать "зачем скрещивать крокодила с чемоданом?", он спросит "как?" ©

Comment: @Sh4dow, не понял.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Что Вы... Конечно это не будет велосипедом. Нормальные шаблонизаторы щас вообще трудно найти.

Ну, например, можете добавить цикл foreach, ну чтобы можно было например вывести массив данных. Скажем так:

```
Массив состоит из следующих значений:
<FOREACH($VAR_1)>
    {$VAR_1}
<END FOREACH>
```

Ну смысл вы поняли. Можно даже туда как-нибудь ключ массива привязать (т.е. `foreach($array as $key => $value)`). Например так:

```
Массив состоит из следующих значений:
<FOREACH($VAR_1$)>
    {$VAR_1_KEY$}: {$VAR_1$} 
<END FOREACH>
```

Можно добавить выполнение функций. Ну хотя у вас на это есть алиасы вроде. Вообще посмотрите [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/55207/). Довольно хороший шаблонизатор. Мне понравился. Единственно, что я бы от себя туда добавил, это запрет добавление обычного php-кода (ну просто мне очень нужна эта фича!).

Comment: Это идея, циклы попробую сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: Опа, а как же ассоциативные массивы сделать...

Comment: Ну сделайте в этом блоке переменную какую-нибудь и пусть она обозначает ключ массива. Это мое предложение. Т.е. выше же я писал... Что-то типа {$VAR_1_KEY$}. А когда компилируете шаблон, меняете просто ее на $key.

Comment: Извините. Не понял вопроса)

Comment: > Нет. Что Вы... Конечно это не будет велосипедом. Нормальные шаблонизаторы щас вообще трудно найти.

Не хватает тега `<sarcasm>`, кто-нибудь может решить, что вы серьезно :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, простите меня глупого, но для меня это действительно было трудно) И то... После долгих и упорных поисков нашел только тот, который в посте указал))

Answer (score 2):

> > <if{$ALIAS_1$ == 123 && $QUERY$ == 'search'}>

без евала будет трудновато распарсить этот блок (но в общимто реально). А евал это всегда риск, особенно если не вы управляете контентом. Собсвенно я к тому что бы вы придумали попроще синтаксис в котором это можно было бы реализовать.

> > Опа, а как же ассоциативные массивы сделать...

```
{$array.key1.subKey1.subSubKey1}
```

После того как сделаете шаблонизатор попробуйте использовать его в какой-то простенькой, но реальной задаче. И вы сразу поймете всё ли работает правильно и чего действительно не хватает.

+я бы посоветовал еще добавить конвертеры.

```
{$var156|toTimeStr}
```

где toTimeStr келбек функция которая преобразовывает переменную var156.

Поэксперементировав с этим вам наверное захочется добавить параметры в этот конвертор, например что бы задать формат времени, поэтому нужно также учесть параметры:

```
{$var156|toTimeStr 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}
```

или даже именные параметры:

```
{$var156|toTimeStr format='Y-m-d H:i:s'}
```

в общим тут полёт фантазии большой. Но в первую очередь подумайте что действительно нужно Вам.

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне - не лучший формат, по сути я вообще не вижу причин использовать что-то подобное, чистая PHP шаблонизация только в профиль. Если вы хотите сделать действительно хороший шаблонизатор, тогда он должен быть быстрым и красивым. В вашем "концепте" я не вижу ни удобства, ни красоты ( говорю строго за себя ).

А для парсинга, скорее всего прийдется использовать всего понемногу.

Ну и, возможно, сделайте что-бы переменную было по человечески видно, что-то типа `[ someVar ]`, `{ someVar }` etc. т.к. не знаю как остальных, но как по мне - конкретно страдает читабельность такого кода  `$var$`. Вообще, в идеале - было бы неплохо написать код так, что-бы пользователи могли сами выбрать себе разделители, т.е. пускай хоть и `{{{{ var }}}}` или `OLOLOLOvarOLOLOLO` делают если хотят. Ну и довольно важно - реализовать удобные базовые хелперы и возможность написания своих. Хелперы могут быть, например, для рекурсивного вывода, фильтрующими, форматирующими и т.д. и т.п.

Ну и реализуйте кэширование.

Если написать код грамотно - можно будет без особого труда портировать на другие языки программирования.

PS: как сформируете концепт - просмотрите существующие шаблонизаторы и подумайте - значительно отличается ли ваша задумка, сможете ли вы предложить продукт получше и т.д.
Конечно это только если вы не исключительно в учебных целях пишите.

Comment: > Вообще, в идеале - было бы неплохо написать код так, что-бы пользователи могли сами выбрать себе разделители

Уже есть.

> Ну и реализуйте кэширование.

Можно подробнее? Как сделать кеширование в шаблонизаторе? Что кешировать, как, и на сколько?

Comment: Кеширование нужно для того, что-бы, когда шаблон готов - не тратить время на его разбор. Что кешировать и как - зависит от реализации, важно что-бы подьем из кеша был максимально быстрым. По поводу насколько - ну это пользователь будет определять вызовом функции, какие параметры поставить по умолчанию - судите сами

Comment: И было бы чудесно реализовать возможность хранить кеши как в файлах так и в базе данных, более того - дать пользователю возможность самому реализовать хранение и чтение кеша.