# Условные конструкции preg_match

Tags: preg_match, php

Есть определённый текст (шаблон), в нём иногда встречаются строки вида:

```
[if (health == 1) then (var1) else (var2)]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в PHP обрабатывалась данная конструкция, где: health = реальная переменная которая есть в скрипте, а на выходе должен быть массив, с результатами (т.к. таких конструкций может быть несколько. Массив должен в себе содержать либо var1, либо var2 (основываясь на данном примере, т.е. массив содержит содержимое скобок смотря из конструкции.)

Comment: Устроит ли Вас такой вариант:  
1. Внутри круглых скобок все что похоже на имя переменной предваряется знаком доллара.  
2. Во вторую и третью круглую скобку добавляется return.  
3. После второй и третьей скобки ставится точка с запятой и полученная строка обрабатывается eval ом

Comment: вы предлагаете eval()?
У меня была такая идея, но я подумал что можно это реализовать другим, более интересным способом.

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, каким же например? Регулярные выражения сопоставляют текст шаблону, производить вычисления они не способны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вёрстка и php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69622#69669)